# Parse Push notification as invitation to user requesting his response

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform

How can i send a reply back to the Parse cloud code which has send the push notification. THe scenario is that there are 3 users to whom i need to send push, but i want the second and third person to receive push only when the first person rejects the invitation that has been sent as push. The push invokes a dialog with YES or NO options and if the first user responds with NO , the second person should receive a push. How to do this ?

Comment: do you know what you are saying?

Comment: @KKD sorry it got posted by mistake before completing..can you check whether it makes sense now ?

Comment: Since this is tagged android, I am assuming you are talking about GCM push message. The server that you are using to send push must be having GCM reg IDs of all the devices. When yes-no dialog popps up in device 1 call a server API that will send the push to the next device (based on whichever order you choose). I hope I cleared your doubt.

Comment: thanks @KKD . i have that strategy already on table, but i am looking for something like sending back the response using the same connection which has sent the push to me. And i am not using GCM directly, but i am using Parse.com BaaS, which i thin internally uses GCM only. I read somewhere like using GCM CCS we can send a reply back, but in my case i am using parse cloud code functions. What i wish is like the asychronous function in cloud code should process the response coming through the connection which has sent the push. But i am seeing very little possibility for that.